# Как перевести строку во время?

Tags: java, android

Есть строки:

```
String s1 = "7:00";
String s2 = "12:34:56";
String s3 = "13:20";
```

Как их быстро перевести в int

```
int hh, mm, ss;
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно, зачем переводить в Целое число? Хотите получить время в миллисекундах? Или вы просто хотите перевести строку в Date?

Comment: надо получить в часах: float result = hh + mm/60. + ss/3600.;

Comment: То есть, из строки `"12:34:56"`  получить просто `12`? Или `int hour = 12; int min = 34; int sec = 56`?

Comment: Да int hour = 12; int min = 34; int sec = 56 и потом должно получиться примерно 12,58222222222222

Comment: проблема в другом - формат записи разный!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static int[] unpack(String time) throws NullPointerException, NumberFormatException {
    int[] output = {0, 0, 0};
    String[] parts = time.split(":");
    for (int x = 0; x < parts.length; x++) {
        if (x >= output.length)
            break;
        output[x] = Integer.parseInt(parts[x]);
    }
    return output;
}

int[] result = unpack("12:34:56");
int hh = result[0];
int mm = result[1];
int ss = result[2];
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно разбить строку на массив строк по разделителю `:`, затем преобразовать этот массив строк в массив чисел и в зависимости от длины получившегося массива (2 или 3) интерпретировать этот массив как `[hh, mm]` или `[hh, mm, ss]`.

```
String s = "12:34:56";
int[] numbers = Stream
        .of(s.split(":"))
        .mapToInt(Integer::valueOf)
        .toArray();

if (numbers.length == 2) {
    int hh = numbers[0];
    int mm = numbers[1];
    // ...
} else if (numbers.length == 3) {
    int hh = numbers[0];
    int mm = numbers[1];
    int ss = numbers[2];
    // ...
} else {
    throw new Exception();
}
```

Если хочется сделать покороче, то можно попробовать так:

```
String s = "12:34:56";
String[] numbers = (s.length() <= 5 ? s + ":00" : s).split(":");
int hh = Integer.valueOf(numbers[0]);
int mm = Integer.valueOf(numbers[1]);
int ss = Integer.valueOf(numbers[2]);
```

Comment: я примерно так и сделал, но хотелось покороче как-то.

Comment: @kaaa, сделал немного покороче

Comment: Спасибо большое всем за помощь !!! Теперь я знаю несколько способов, как решать подобные задачи.